# Any quicker way to find the residues here?

Tags: contour-integration

I have to integrate $\dfrac{1}{(z-4)(z^7-1)}$ w.r.t $z$ along $C : |z|=2$.

7 poles of the function lie inside $C$ and $z=4$ lies outside. I am trying to find the answer by applying residue theorem. i.e. $2\pi i \sum (\text{residues inside }C)$, but it is becoming too lengthy to handle. Any leads?

Comment: You can also calculate the integral by considering only those residues at points outside the contour. So you only have two summands (for $4$ and $\infty$)

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=2}f(z)\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}f(2e^{it})\,{2ie^{it}}\,dt
=\int_0^{2\pi}f(2e^{-it})2ie^{-it}\,dt\\[0.3cm]
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{\frac14\,e^{2it}}\,f\Bigg(\frac1{\frac12\,e^{it}}\Bigg)\,\frac12ie^{it}\,dt
\\[0.3cm]
&=\oint_{|z|=\frac12}\frac1{z^2}\,f\Big(\frac1z\Big)\,dz.
\end{align}
Now your new function is
$$
\frac1{z^2}\,f\Big(\frac1z\Big)=\dfrac{1}{z^2\Big(\dfrac1z-4\Big)\Big(\frac1{z^7}-1\Big)}
=\frac{z^6}{4\Big(z-\dfrac14\Big)(z^7-1)}
$$
and you want to integrate on $|z|=\tfrac12$, so there is a single pole at $z=\tfrac14$. As the pole is simple, the integral is
$$
\frac{2\pi i (1/4)^6}{4((1/4)^7-1)}=\frac{2i\pi}{1-4^7}=-\frac{2i\pi}{16383}.
$$

Comment: How did you replace $2e^{i t}$ by $2e^{-i  t}$??

Comment: I used the substitution $u=2\pi-t$.

Comment: It should be $\int_{|z| = 2} f(z) dz = \int_{|z| = 1/2} f(1/z)/z^2 dz$ (with the same orientation of the circles), without the $1/2$ factor.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.